# How to move views from a ClearCase registry to a new ClearCase registry

Tags: clearcase

I have only one ClearCase registry. But I need to create another one in order to enhance the security. Unregister the vob and register it in the new registry is easy, but how can I move all the views?? I'm talking about two thousand views. So, I need a mechanism to move ALL the views of one vob to a new registry. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to have a script which would:

- `rmtag`
- `unregister`
- `mktag`
- `register` again

(from [`rgy_admin`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/rgy-admin.htm):)

[image]

But that would render the views inoperable: the users would have to delete them (simple delete, no `mkview` required), and [rebuild the view.dat](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21204161) (for snapshot views)

Maybe it would be easier to **declare your second registry server as a backup of your first registry, and once the two servers are in sync, make an rgy switchover** (from "[`rgy_backup`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_rgy_backup.htm)").